# Solving an exponential equation for a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

For a primitive element of the finite field $\alpha$ and $\beta=\alpha^2$, I'm searching for all integer values of $(k,l)$ such that $\beta^l=1+\beta^k$. I have a list of $k$ values which I know are elements of the multiplicative group $\langle \beta \rangle = \langle \alpha^2 \rangle$, but now I must solve for values of $l$ such that $\beta^l=1+\beta^k$ for that given $k$ value. If this equation were over the reals or complex numbers, I could simply take a natural logarithm of both sides and simplify down to get a value for $l$. However, this approach shouldn't work for a finite field. Is there any way to easily find the $l$ value for any given $k$ value without using unnecessarily complicated coding?

Comment: The [discrete log problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Cryptography) (working over a finite field) is difficult in general, which is one reason it is used in encryption schemes. Unless there's something special about elements of the form $1 + \beta^k$, I think determining $\ell$ will be hard.

Comment: For a specific $k$ this is, indeed, the discrete logarithm problem, and no good general method is known. If you, more simply, want the total number of solutions, then something can be said. After all, essentially you are then looking for solutions of $x^2=1+y^2$. That can be settled by rewriting it in the form $1=(x-y)(x+y)$. A linear transformation then shows that $x+y$ and $x-y$ are independent variables (except in characteristic two, when it becomes trivial: $x=1+y$. Anyway, the exponents are a tall order.